# SSIS - How to check if the value in a column matches (is the same) another column

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I am doing a validation process, trying to use conditional split to see if current manager = past manager in a salesperson database (look at image link below). If they don't match, I will later use it to signal the shift.

I tried doing [manager_2017] == [manager_2018] but it doesn't run. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't it run since it's a True or False case?

I am using SSIS with Visual Studio 2017.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUXEk.png]

Comment: Could you click the Edit button and expand on "it doesn't run"

Comment: I found the error, the sample had null values which the SSIS needs some specification on how to handle them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While awaiting clarification on the precise error, the supplied syntax is correct. `[manager_2017] == [manager_2018]` is a valid SSIS expression which evaluates to a boolean type (DT_BOOL).

I find it's handy to add a Derived Column before things like a Conditional Split and create explicit columns to hold my logical flags. It makes it easier to add a data viewer/data tap into the mix to ensure I've covered the cases.

```
IsSameManager  `[manager_2017] == [manager_2018]`
```

Then in my Conditional Split, I'd have two output streams. Default and a new one "Retained Manager" I can then split on a single column `IsSameManager`

There are two things I can think of that might be causing an error, based on your sample data. The first is that column names are case sensitive in SSIS. Your spreadsheet has an uppercase for the first column "Salesperson_id" and lowercase for the manager columns. If they are represented as `Manager_2017` then the expression would have to change to `[Manager_2017]`

The other possibility is data typing. If one of those columns was interpreted as a large data type (DT_NTEXT/DT_TEXT) then comparisons between it at a non-large type (DT_WSTR, DT_STR) won't be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, but thanks for the tips.
Basically the sample had null values so I had to specify how to deal with those before SSIS would run.

So the formula ended up as:
[manager_2017] == [manager_2018] && !ISNULL([manager_2017]) && !ISNULL([manager_2018])

Obviously the sample I am using is much bigger, I have multiple hierarchy levels to compare and I simplified it for the purpose of asking, so I ended up overlooking the null values.